# How do/should I prepare a folder for stored image, reference from sql, save the image location using C#

Tags: c#, sql, file, image, save

Really hoping someone can provide some code sample or point me in the right direction (with examples C#.net). I did try to check if this question was asked before.. but didn't really find code samples which answered all my questions.

1. Image folder for saved files -should this be in the solution or somewhere else
2. What kind of data type - will vchar(150) for example for ok?
3. What will be the typical/most ideal code to save the image in the folder location and write the image location in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2008 I would use the filestream data type. It allows for what you want to do but totally integrated with the DB (you see the column -- image -- as a varbinary(MAX)).

Comment: I do not want to save the images in the DB, only in a folder and reference from DB.

Comment: With filestream this is exactly what it does (I think)... http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1489

Answer (score 0):

Not wholly sure what you mean but this could point you in the right direction:

1) Keep it in the solution unless it is to be called by more than application
2) Just use Varchar(Max) or NVarchar(Max) depending on your encoding type
3) You'll need: 
 - In db, a stored procedure to write the image location to a table.In 
 - In the C#,  a connection object and a command object to call a stored
   procedure

Answer (score 0):

NTFS - Suports multiple Data Streams for each file.

NetFrameWork do´nt include support for those streams.

You can use Interop to gain access to Alternate Data Streams.

Sample Csharp code on CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csadsdetectorarticle.aspx

Note.: When you download a file from internet on Xp, the Dowloaded files has two Streams, MyFile and MyFile:Zone.Identifier

This stream contains some like this:
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3

Comment: Code Project also includes "Accessing alternative data-streams of files on an NTFS volume". This encapsulates those methods on a Dll. http://beta.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=2670&av=33357